# Add scroll view while bottom navigation reamins intact

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview

How to add `scrollview` to this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="143dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/warmbanner" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="169dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/chestday" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sh" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: add XML as code here, not as external link.

Comment: Please, provide at least a couple of sentences more, so if not you, but other people can help and attach XML to question.

Comment: What is your exact requirement?. Please elaborate..!!

Comment: Check my below answer, paste it in your `ConstraintLayout` and try.

Comment: app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation" -cannot resolve symbol and multiple root tags error at the end @UmangBurman

Comment: Did you write where I said you to, Check my updated answer.

Comment: yep but i cant see anything in the design and the app crashes ! @UmangBurman

Comment: Oh It works fine in my laptop though.

Comment: I implemented scroll view ,but the btm navigation scrolls along the content! [my xml code](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/nvNwBNSW) @UmangBurman

Comment: Because ScrollView covers the BottomNavigation

Comment: Try This: https://pastebin.com/zHBzb9sB

Comment: Thank you @UmangBurman later adding `app:menu="@menu/navigation"`in your code,it worked! BTW  the reason i can't improvise your code is i'm new and i don't know java very well.College teaches that only in the 4th sem!

Comment: I understand, Your welcome. Yeah I did not add `navigation` because I did not have that, Sorry forgot to tell you though. Keep going and you will master android soon. Take Care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Just paste this code inside your parent top-level `ConstraintLayout` and try:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="143dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="169dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

Hope it helps.

See the below code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    (Write Here)

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```